# Annotate vs Serializer Method Fields in DRF

Tags: python, django-rest-framework

I know that there is more than one way to return aggregated fields (not stored in the database) from an endpoint.

One using the annotate method and other through serializers using the serializer method field.

Models

```
class Collection(models.Model):
   title = models.CharField(max_length=255)
   featured_product = models.ForeignKey(
    'Product', on_delete=models.SET_NULL, null=True, related_name='+', blank=True)

class Product(models.Model):
    title = models.CharField(max_length=255)
    slug = models.SlugField()
    description = models.TextField(null=True, blank=True)
    unit_price = models.DecimalField(max_digits=6,decimal_places=2,validators= 
         [MinValueValidator(1)])
    inventory = models.IntegerField(validators=[MinValueValidator(0)])
    last_update = models.DateTimeField(auto_now=True)
    collection = models.ForeignKey(Collection, on_delete=models.PROTECT, 
         related_name='collections')
    promotions = models.ManyToManyField(Promotion, blank=True)
```

Output:

```
{
   {
        "id": 7,
        "title": "Baking",
        "products_count": 0
   },
   ...
}
```

Annotate Method:

serializer

```
class CollectionSerializer(serializers.ModelSerializer):
    products_count = serializers.IntegerField()
    class Meta:
        model = Collection
        fields = ['id', 'title', 'products_count']
```

Views

```
class CollectionList(APIView):
    def get(self, request):
        queryset = Collection.objects.annotate(products_count=Count('collections')).all()
        serializer = CollectionSerializer(queryset, many=True)
        return Response(serializer.data)
```

[image]

Serializer Method Field:
Serializer

```
class CollectionSerializer(serializers.ModelSerializer):
    products_count = serializers.SerializerMethodField()
    class Meta:
        model = Collection
        fields = ['id', 'title', 'products_count']

    def get_products_count(self, collection: Collection):
        return collection.collections.count()
```

Views

```
class CollectionList(APIView):
    def get(self, request):    
        queryset = Collection.objects.prefetch_related('collections').all()
        serializer = CollectionSerializer(queryset, many=True)
        return Response(serializer.data)
```

[image]

As you can see both methods return the desired output but the sql queries are different. Which is the recommended method and why is query different?

Comment: When the serializer starts its work, the query is already evaluated. At that point, the IDs are already known.

Answer (score 0):

From the [**`prefetch_related`**..[Django-doc]](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/models/querysets/#prefetch-related) docs:

> Remember that, as always with QuerySets, any subsequent chained methods which imply a different database query will ignore previously cached results, and retrieve data using a fresh database query

The serializer method executes extra queries because the prefetch was cancelled/not used since `.count()` implies a new database query. So to utilise the prefetch, you can use `len()`:

```py
class CollectionSerializer(serializers.ModelSerializer):
    # ...

    def get_products_count(self, collection: Collection):
        # Use the prefetched collections and avoid doing extra queries
        return len(collection.collections.all())
```

As for which is the recommended approach, if you just need the count of the products per collection, I would go with annotate since that only uses one query.

The prefetch approach does 2 queries: one to get the collections, and another to get the related products for each collection.

Comment: Thank you for your answer. I'm getting RelatedManager has no len() error when I try this.

Comment: Ah sorry try to use `len(collection.collections.all())`